# Angle trisection using a Cardioid

Tags: euclidean-geometry

How does one proceed to trisect an angle using the cardioid?
It is known that Etienne Pascal, father of Blaise Pascal, has devised a way to do it. I haven´t found the method in my search on the literature.

Best Regards.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that a cardioid is suited to trisection? Is your motivation to find a novel way to use the cardioid? or a novel way to trisect an angle?

Comment: A [trisectrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisectrix) is a curve that can be used to trisect an arbitrary angle. Cardioid isn't listed on above wiki entry. The [Limaçon trisectrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on_trisectrix) seems to be the trisectrix closest to a cardioid.

Comment: The Limaçon trisectrix is listed in deed. There is an observation in the book The Budget of Trisections (Underwood Dudley) at pages 9-10 that goes like this:
"Although the trisection is no longer the obsession it was to Greek mathematicians, new methods have been devised in modern times. Etienne Pascalthe father of Blaise (1623-1662) the mathematician, philosopher,
and writer, trisected with a cardioid."

Comment: @PetruchiodeSãoZeno: Ah. Well, then ... You already have it on good authority that it is indeed *possible* to trisect an angle with a cardioid. So, your question really is: *What method did Pascal, Sr, (and/or others) devise?* Interestingly, a 1907 *American Mathematical Monthly* article ["The Trisection Problem" (JSTOR link)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2968490?seq=1) opens with a casual mention that "The solution of this problem by means of the quadratrix, conchoid, and the cardioid are well known [...]".

Comment: Thank you, Blue. I have edited the question now so that the initial answers keep sounding useful. I realized that I was in fact interested in the method itself. I am not putting in doubt what these authors have said.

Comment: Curiously, [this description of the "Limaçon of Pascal"](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Curves/Limacon.html), $r = b + 2 a\cos\theta$, states that "When $b=2a$, then the limacon becomes a cardioid while if $b=a$ then it becomes a trisectrix." Likewise for "limacon" entries on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limaçon) and [Xah Code](http://xahlee.info/SpecialPlaneCurves_dir/LimaconOfPascal_dir/limaconOfPascal.html), the cardioid and trisectrix are mentioned as separate special cases of the curve. I wonder if "cardioid" is being (mis)used to mean "limaçon" by Dudley and others.

Comment: It seems to be a possibility although I think it's not likely, for the cardioid is a singular curve.